# I have a bug in my polynomial class

Tags: python, class, debugging

I am learning about class by building a class that represents polynomials. I know that theres a nice way of doing polynomials in numpy btw.
I have an add, multiply and call dunner methods defined. Polynomials are sums of terms of the form `a*x**b` so the class is called 'sot'. 
Any instance of sot contains self.term which is a list of pears of numbers `[a,b]`. each per represent `a*x**b`. 
the add method returns a new instance of sot with the concatenation of self.terms with other.terms as the argument

sot take a list of pears as its argument in its initialization

Thee problem is that when I add two instances of sot a+b a is changed, and so that if I repeat the addition a+b I get a different result.
The same does not happen with my multiplication method.

Can anyone see what's going on here?

```
#The class 'sot' represents a Sum Of Terms of the form a*x^b, aka a polinomeal
#On creating a new instanse, sot must be fead a list containg its terms.
#Each terms is represented by a list of two vareavles. [a,b] represesnting a*x^b
#Eg: a = sot(( [1,2], [2,1], [3,0] )) represents x^2 + 2x + 3
#Caling an instanse will return the evaluation of the polinomeal
# If the terms of sot are given as a tuple (eg sot(( (1,2) )) ) the object will not function as intended.
# Creating a sot of no terms, and empty polinomeal, must be done with squer brackets. eg sot([[0,3]])
# This vesion of the file prints out what its doing in the simplifying step, this is for debuging perposes



class sot:

    def __init__(self,tupe):
        #The first step un-packs the argument into a list of terms
        self.term=[]
        for t in tupe:
            print("add " + str(t) + " to " + str(self.term))
            self.term = self.term+[t]
        #Simpler is a method that simplifys the polinomeal
        self.simpler() 

    def simpler(self):
        #The first step is to sort the polinnomeal by the assending powers eg c + x + x^2 ...

        print("simplifying " +  str(self))
        self.term = sorted(self.term,key = lambda element: element[1] ) 
        print("sorted "+str(self))

        # now this while loop will inspect the list of terms to see if anny 
            # (a) have a zero coefichent
                # in which case there removed from the list
            # (b) have the same power 
                # in which case the terms second of ther terms will be poped form the list 
                # sotored in 'carry'  and its constant 'carry[0]' will be added to the first term
        # If the loop has not run then ther must be onlly one element and it must not have been
        #  checked for beeing zero 

        i=0     
        while i < len(self.term)-1:
            print("checking " + str(i) + " out of " + str( len(self.term)-2))
            if self.term[i][0] ==0:
                self.term.remove(i)
                print("removeing zero")
            if self.term[i][1] ==self.term[i+1][1]:
                print("adding similers")
                carry = self.term.pop(i+1)
                print("carry term "+str(carry))
                self.term[i][0] = self.term[i][0] +carry[0]
                print("new sum "+ str(self))
            i=i+1

        if i==0 & self.term[0][0] == 0:
            self.term = []
            print("the list has one term and that term is zero")

        print("simplifyed compleat " + str(self))


    def __call__(self,x):
        # the result of a call the sum of each term, remember that each term [a,b] represents a*x**b
        result = 0
        for t in self:
            result = result + t[0]*x**t[1]
        return result

    def __repr__(self):
        string = []
        for t in self:
            string = string+ [str(t[0]) + "x**" + str(t[1])]
        return " + ".join(string)

    def __len__(self):
        #The length of a sot is just the number of terms
        return len(self.term)

    def __iter__(self):
        # The iteration of a sot steps throgh the list of terms starting from the zerothe
        # and returning each tem as it dose so
        self.i=0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.i < len(self):
            self.i=self.i+1
            return self.term[self.i-1]
        else:
            raise StopIteration


    def __add__(self,other):
        # adding tow sots together is the same as haveing a new sot, so for a + b there list of terms 
        # are concatanated and fed into a new instanse of sot
        argument = self.term+other.term
        return  sot(argument)

    def __mul__(self,other):
        # multiplication of sots is done with the distributive law:
            # sum_i(x_i)*sum_j(x_j) = sum_i(x_i *sum_j(x_j)) = sum_i(sum_j(x_i*x_j))
        # this is realised with two imbeded for loops
        # when two terms are multiplyed, the constant parts are multiplyed and the powers are added:
            #(ax**b)*(cx**d) = (a*c)x**(b+d)
        # The relustant list of terms is fed into a new instanse of sot
        argument = []
        for s in self:
            for o in other:
                argument = argument + [[ s[0]*o[0] , s[1]+o[1] ]]
        return sot(argument)
```

Comment: Your objects are sharing the sublists of the `term` lists.

Comment: As an aside, this is not a good way to implement `__iter__` and `__next__`. You almost certainly don't want your `sot` objects to be iterator at all, so you shouldn't be implementing `__next__`, just `__iter__`. Anyway, you really just want to iterate over `self.term`, so your `__iter__` method should just delegate to `iter(self.term)`

Comment: Also, `&` is *not the logical and operator*, it is a bitwise-and operator. use `and`

Comment: Also note, `self.term = self.term+[t]` is **incredibly inefficient**. Use `self.term.append(t)`

Comment: Iv changed & to 'and', +[t] to .append(t) and removed __next__ and set __inter__ to return inter(self.term). Thanks for the tips.